# In how many ways can '$6$' things be distributed equally among $2$ groups?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can '$6$' things be distributed 
>   equally among $2$ groups ?

I tried

$\dbinom{6}{3}\times \dbinom{3}{3}\times 3!\times 3!$

But I am not sure if it is correct .

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Why have you multiplied by 3! and 3! ?

Comment: To permute $3$ objects.

Comment: Ncmathsadist has already answered the question.

Comment: Why scare quotes around 6? Is is not really 6 after all?

Comment: actually it was $'3\times 2'$.

Answer (score 7):

It's $6\choose 3$ if you have groups $A$ and $B$.  You choose three items and give them to $A$; there are $6\choose 3$ ways to do this.  You then give the remaining to group $B$.

The $3!s$ are called for if you stipulate the order in which the groups receive the items is important. Otherwise, not.

$${6\choose 3} = 20.$$

If the two groups are indistinguishable and you are just interested in partitioning the items into two parts of size three, we have an overcount of a factor of 2.  In that case there are only $10$ ways.  You must be careful about exactly what you are counting.